# How do I find the correct Modeline to connect my computer to my Televsion

Tags: tv, modelines

I've been trying to hook up a Ubuntu computer with my Panasonic TH-42PA60A Plasma television for weeks now. My original question was asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/177087/how-can-i-configure-xorg-conf-to-display-ubuntu-on-a-plasma-television#comment220461_177087), which includes all the specifications about the Television in detail and how I've connected the computer to the televsion.

So far, I've tried hooking up three other computers; 2 Ubuntu computers with fairly new graphic cards, and a Windows XP computer. None of them have been able to display an image on the television.

The closest I've come to getting a picture up is with my small laptop running Ubuntu, however the image came out all purple and distorted. I had gotten the image by adding extra modes via the xrandr command, using a process similar to described [here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-change-display-resolution-settings-using-xrandr.html).

I realize it might be possible to get this working if I had the correct modeline. I've checked the [Modeline database](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Modeline_Database), but the Panasonic TH-42PA60A is not listed.

How can I find the correct modeline for my television. What commands can I use?

I've read that there may be a danger of damaging my TV when doing things like this. What things should I avoid to prevent damaging my television?

Comment: In what way was the image distorted? You may want to start at small resolutions until you can get one to work and then move up.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the `cvt` program. It's preinstalled in your Ubuntu system.

You should first determine the resolution and refresh rate your TV uses.
Then use:

```
cvt <horizontal-resolution> <vertical-resolution> <refresh>
```

For example for my wide screen laptop:

```
cvt 1440 900 60
```

Output:

```
\# 1440x900 59.89 Hz (CVT 1.30MA) hsync: 55.93 kHz; pclk: 106.50 MHz    
Modeline "1440x900_60.00"  106.50  1440 1528 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync
```

I can't give you any assurances about compatibility with your equipment.

---

I did try this one on mine.

```
xrandr --newmode "1440x900_60.00" 106.50 1440 1528 1672 1904 900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode LVDS 1440x900_60.00
xrandr --output LVDS --mode 1440x900_60.00
```

Output from `xrandr`

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1440 x 900, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
LVDS connected 1440x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 367mm x 230mm
   1440x900       60.0 +
   1280x854       59.9  
   1280x800       59.8  
   1280x720       59.9  
   1152x768       59.8  
   1024x768       59.9  
   800x600        59.9  
   848x480        59.7  
   720x480        59.7  
   640x480        59.4  
   1440x900_60.00   59.9*
```

---

Another option is videogen which you can install with `sudo apt install videogen`